# Etherscan api for Ropsten testnet

Tags: tokens, erc-20, etherscan, balances, explorer-api

I found this endpoint is to obtain the token balance from Ethereum blockchain, however, I noticed that this function doesn't work on Rospten network.
Please advise

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x6bb495e358d7aab0540d9b38996e715fcc4f1ba2&address=0x63a5f2232a519321237e31d0a79f6c20e0e652d3&tag=latest&apikey=JKXR76EA1NK9XSKES1T2BNYBZ41T3BJ2JH
```

Possible I could have the same function works on Ropsten network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an update
you can access it from this [link](https://docs.etherscan.io/getting-started/endpoint-urls)

Somthing like this

> https://api-goerli.etherscan.io

Comment: Hello. This does not really ad anymore information than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes but I couldn't add comment to that because I got a low rank haha, so just added this

Answer (score 7):

According to [the docs](https://docs.etherscan.io/v/ropsten-etherscan/api-endpoints/accounts), you must simply append "-ropsten" to the subdomain. Your URL should look as follows:

```
https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x6bb495e358d7aab0540d9b38996e715fcc4f1ba2&address=0x63a5f2232a519321237e31d0a79f6c20e0e652d3&tag=latest&apikey=JKXR76EA1NK9XSKES1T2BNYBZ41T3BJ2JH
```

Comment: @shane- I have a quick question for you here, can I have my local private geth node running on my local server with the etherscan api ?